# Suspending by closing laptop lid causes issues

Tags: suspend, laptop, 17.10

I have a Razer Blade Stealth, and a few weeks ago I upgraded to 17.10. Everything was going great until I closed my laptop lid, and reopened it. Everything would look normal for ~10 seconds and then the screen would go dark and the computer would suspend. Unlock the computer, and the process repeats itself. This behavior would not stop unless I was able to quickly log in and restart the computer.

At first, I thought it was a problem with suspending. But after some digging and additional tests, I do not think this is the case. If I suspend the computer from the command line or the power button then I can resume with no issues. However, if I do it by closing the lid (as one would normally do 99% of the time) then the issues come up again.

I guess my question is: what kind of issue does this point to? I'm no power user, and the way I've got around it is by going into my `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file and changing it so that `HandleLidSwitch=ignore`, but this just makes it so the laptop doesn't do anything on lid close. Does anyone know what a more elegant fix to this issue could be, or where to look?